# Mysql - Using limit N and check if N lines recieved

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am answering some questions in LeetCode.
and I am using the LIMIT(N) to receive N lines in the response.
But i dont know if i have less then N lines.
In this case I should return Null...
How can I add this check => if i have less then N line return null

the SQL query  should return the nth highest salary

Comment: First start by adding table structure, some example data and expected output/results to the question.. i adivce you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*) from t) >= n
limit n;
```

Comment: Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.
Employee table consists of two columns (Id, Salary.)
For example, given the above Employee table ( 1, 100 ;  2 ,200  ; 3 300), the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.